# Errors occur when I extract values from ncdf file in R

Tags: r, extract, ncdf4

I wrote a function to extract values from ncdf files, as shown below:

```
precresults <- function(x){
    library(magrittr)
    library(ncdf4)
    library(raster)
    library(ncdf.tools)
    ##library(ncf)
    re1 <- brick(nl1a[x])
    re <- extract(re1,zuobiao)
        ####zuobiao stands for the coordinate of the targeted sites
    ###extract(zuobiao)
    return(re)
}

###precresults(20)
precresults11 <- lapply(1:420, precresults)
```

"lapply" function is used to extract values for multiple site.

However, an error occurs:

> Error in UseMethod("extract_") :    no applicable method for
>   'extract_' applied to an object of class "c('RasterBrick', 'Raster',
>   'RasterStackBrick', 'BasicRaster')"

How can we solve such error?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark - is there any masking going on? Perhaps you could try using `raster::extract`. My guess is that right now, `magrittr::extract` is being used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I finally solve my problem based on your comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think Roman is correct, `magrittr::extract` is masking `raster::extract`. In the example provided you do not use magrittr, but you may use it elsewhere, so use `raster::extract` rather then `extract`. Your function could be rewritten as:

```
library(raster)
precresults <- function(x){
    re1 <- brick(nl1a[x])
    raster::extract(re1, zuobiao)
}
precresults11 <- lapply(1:420, precresults)
```

Or like this:

```
library(raster)
x <- matrix(nrow=length(zuobiao), ncol=420)
for (i in 1:420) {
    re1 <- brick(nl1a[i])
    x[,i] <- raster::extract(re1, zuobiao)
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I successfully solve my problem based on your suggestions.